# ASP.NET drag and drop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

i am new with ASP.NET
My task is create a drag and drop system.
For now i am using up and down for each element of the page see the screen shot. How to manage the drag and drop with the same idea of ordering the objects?
[image: Example image]

And this is a code

```
protected void lb_up_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
    ChangeItemNumber(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()), -1); 
} 
protected void lb_down_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
    ChangeItemNumber(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()), 1); 
}
private void ChangeItemNumber(int id, int changeValue) 
{ 
    Dal dal = new Dal(); 
    var itemToChange = dal.GetSale(id); 
    Sale replacedLesson = null; 
    if (changeValue == -1) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < rp_sales.Items.Count; i++) 
        { 
            if (((HiddenField)rp_sales.Items[i].FindControl("hf_id")).Value == id.ToString()) 
            { 
            replacedLesson = dal.GetSale(int.Parse(((HiddenField)rp_sales.Items[i - 1].FindControl("hf_id")).Value)); 
            break; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < rp_sales.Items.Count; i++) 
        { 
            if (((HiddenField)rp_sales.Items[i].FindControl("hf_id")).Value == id.ToString()) 
            { 
                replacedLesson = dal.GetSale(int.Parse(((HiddenField)rp_sales.Items[i + 1].FindControl("hf_id")).Value)); 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    //replacedLesson = dal.GetNextCategoryInLine((int)itemToChange.OrderNumber,chk_activeOnly.Checked); 
    }

    ViewState["main"] = itemToChange.ID; 
    ViewState["sub"] = replacedLesson.ID; 

    var num = (int)itemToChange.OrderNumber; 
    itemToChange.OrderNumber = replacedLesson.OrderNumber; 
    replacedLesson.OrderNumber = num; 

    // NormelizeLessonOrder(); 
    dal.Save(); 
    LoadData(); 
}
```

ASPX Code

```
<ItemTemplate> 
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit_tableRow"></asp:Literal> 
<td> 
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hf_counter" /> 
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hf_id" /> 
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="showLoad();" Font-Size="XX-Large" runat="server" ID="lb_up" OnCommand="lb_up_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'><span class="fa fa-2x fa-caret-up"></span></asp:LinkButton> 
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="showLoad();" Font-Size="XX-Large" runat="server" ID="lb_down" OnCommand="lb_down_Command" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'><span class="fa fa-2x fa-caret-down"></span></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
</td> 
<td> 
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img_logo" Height="50px" /> 
</td> 
<td> 
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_name" /><br /> 
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_Status"></asp:Label> 
</td> 
<td> 
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_Title" Font-Bold="true" /><br /> 
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_data" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label> 
</td> 
<td> 
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_category"></asp:Label> 
</td> 
<td> 
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_totalSales"></asp:Label> 
</td> 
<td> 
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit_view"></asp:Literal> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I have taken a moment to format your code for you. Please note what I've done and take the time to format before posting in the future. It makes your code easier to read and more likely for you to receive an answer.

Comment: Should this change be reflected everytime when the user visits the page? I mean the positions has to be retained? If so, try including `jquery-ui` which has `drag` and `drop` option and you can use various events available with the plugin to save the order in database and sort it with the order number stored in database whenever the user visits the page..

Comment: Check this! http://www.developer.com/lang/using-html5-drag-and-drop-in-asp.net.html, I think it's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please use Jquery-UI. Following links can be useful for you:

http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: But this effective only ui. I need the same logic as i have with up and down btn to make it drag on drop.